# Use dst argument to reuse previously allocated memory with the cvtColor function in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am implementing a program where I need to have an array of images which are reused (for speed purposes). I thought I could easily create a multidimensional numpy array and reuse each plane as a grayscale image without reallocating new memory, but I am having trouble doing so. Below is a piece of code I create just to illustrate this (this is a simplified version of what I need, just to illustrate my point):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Access camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('Main process')

# Confirm we are able to acquire images (and initialize the frame variable)
ret, rgb_frame = cap.read()
if ret is False:
    print('Error, unable to acquire frame...')
    exit(0)

NUM_BUFFERS = 3

gray_frames_array = np.zeros(
    (rgb_frame.shape[0], rgb_frame.shape[1], NUM_BUFFERS),
    dtype=rgb_frame.dtype)

i = 0
while True:
    ret, _ = cap.read(rgb_frame)
    if ret is False:
        print('Error, unable to acquire frame...')
        exit(0)
    cv2.cvtColor(src=rgb_frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,
                 dst=gray_frames_array[:, :, i])
    cv2.imshow('Main process', gray_frames_array[:, :, i])
    if cv2.waitKey(5) == 27:
        break
    # Use th next "buffer"
    i = (i+1) % NUM_BUFFERS

print('done')
```

My mistake is probably from my Matlab background, but, as it is, I would expect this program to just work without any memory being allocated during the "While True" cycle. However, I get the error:

```
Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'dst'
```

I know that if I use a list of [height, width] numpy arrays, instead of a [height, width,NUM_BUFFERS], it will work just fine but I was looking to get this working with a single multidimensional numpy array.

Comment: Not possible with this arrangement of dimensions -- the view produced by `gray_frames_array[:, :, i]` has a memory layout that can't be handled by `cv::Mat`. The only way this can work is if you make `NUM_BUFFERS` the first dimension -- `(NUM_BUFFERS, rgb_frame.shape[0], rgb_frame.shape[1])`.

Comment: BTW, if you upgrade OpenCV to a recent build (say 4.5.x), you should get much better error message that actually hits at what the problem is: `Layout of the output array dst is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)`.

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek, it solved the problem indeed. I added an answer for future reference based on your input.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Dan Masek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) for pointing out the correct answer. I just shifted the dimensions and it does not give an error anymore.

Although the code is very similiar, I am leaving it here for future reference.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Access camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('Main process')

# Confirm we are able to acquire images (and initialize the frame variable)
ret, rgb_frame = cap.read()
if ret is False:
    print('Error, unable to acquire frame...')
    exit(0)

NUM_BUFFERS = 3

gray_frames_array = np.zeros(
    (NUM_BUFFERS, rgb_frame.shape[0], rgb_frame.shape[1]),
    dtype=rgb_frame.dtype)

i = 0
while True:
    ret, _ = cap.read(rgb_frame)
    if ret is False:
        print('Error, unable to acquire frame...')
        exit(0)
    cv2.cvtColor(src=rgb_frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY,
                 dst=gray_frames_array[i, :, :])
    cv2.imshow('Main process', gray_frames_array[i, :, :])
    if cv2.waitKey(5) == 27:
        break
    # Use th next "buffer"
    i = (i+1) % NUM_BUFFERS

print('done')
```